# Finding the common modulus given many congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Consider the following relationships:

$a_1 \equiv b_1 \mod{g}$

$a_2 \equiv b_2 \mod{g}$

$\cdots $

$a_n \equiv b_n \mod{g}$

Where:

- All values $a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$ are known
- All values $b_1, b_2, ... , b_n$ are unknown
- $g$ is an unknown modulus
- $n$ is an unknown limit
- It is known that such a relationship exist for all values $a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$
- All the numbers are generated randomly (AKA: $g$ is not intentionally prime and there is no intentional coprime relationships), so an [RSA common modulus attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16283/how-to-use-common-modulus-attack) is not intentional)

Question is: what would be the **fastest** way to find $g$ and/or all of $b_1, b_2, ... , b_n$ values?

I do realize that a brute-force attack would definitely reveal it, especially if the bit space is not high, but I'm looking for an easier and less noisy way. Does such a way exist?

Comment: "What would be the fastest way to find $g$ and/or all of $b_n$ values?"  I am **blindly guessing** that this is actually two questions: [1] $g$ is known and $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n$ are all unknown [2] $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n$ are all known and $g$ is unknown.  In [1], one might reasonably presume that you want $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n$ to each be elements in $\{0,1,2,\cdots, (g-1)\}.$  If true, you could employ the Euclidean Algorithm : $a_1 = Pg + b_1.$  In [2], $g$ could be **any** common divisor of $(a_1 - b_1), (a_2 - b_2), \cdots, (a_n - b_n).$

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for answering. Apologies for not being clear **both** $b_1, b_2, ... , b_n$ are UNKNOWN as well as $g$. Only known information is that such a relationship exist, as well as all values $a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$

Comment: I was afraid that you were going to say that.  My fear is because in that case, your query **has no answer**.  For example, the collective (mod [unknown] $y$) equations $a_1 \equiv x_1, a_2 \equiv x_2, \cdots, a_n \equiv x_n,$ where you are trying to **solve** for $y, x_1, \cdots, x_n,$ is **unanswerable**.  There is no leverage on which to base an attack strategy.

Comment: @user2661923 Many thanks for your answer again. I've updated the question with that requirement. Assuming there's no answer to that query, does that mean that such a relationship effectively _hides_ all values of $b_1, b_2, ... , b_n$ as well as $g$? Pardon my ignorance, but is this a known cryptographic primitive?

Comment: I have no idea.  Just out of curiosity how would you even try to solve for $y, x_1, x_2, x_3$ given the (mod $y$) equations $18 \equiv x_1, 19 \equiv x_2, 20 \equiv x_3$?  Do you even know whether (for example) $x_1$ is required to be $\leq 18$?  Extending the question, regardless of whether $x_1$ must be $\leq 18$, is it not true that for these 3 equations, $y$ can be **any positive integer** (presumably) $> 1$?

Comment: "I do realize that a brute-force attack would definitely reveal it"  Uh, No it wouldn't. .......  For any number $b_k$ we will have $b_k \equiv A \mod{}$ for some $W$.  And for every $g$ we know that $A \equiv u\pmod g$ for some $u$ so each statement gives us *ZERO* information at all.  We can't solve something with *ZERO* information.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have enough information to find anything, because you introduce a new unknown with every added equation.

When you start off with $a_1 \equiv b_1 \pmod g$, then any value of $g$ is possible, and $b_1$ can be any of the infinitely many values $a_1 + k_1 g$ for any $k_1 \in \mathbb Z$.

For each equation $a_i \equiv b_i \pmod g$ you add, any existing hypothesis $(b_1, b_2, \dots, b_{i-1}, g)$ can be extended to solve this equation as well, in infinitely many ways, by setting $b_i = a_i + k_i g$ for any $k_i \in \mathbb Z$.

You might be able to make guesses about which values of $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n, g$ are more likely than others, if you know the law by which they are randomly chosen (and how you receive the values $a_i$ - for example, is it true that each $a_i$ is between $0$ and $g-1$?)

Answer (score 0):

"I do realize that a brute-force attack would definitely reveal it"

No, you don't, and no it wouldn't.

"but I'm looking for an easier and less noisy way. Does such a way exist?"

Not only does no easier way exist, no hard way exist.

Note: each state gives you absolutely *no* information at all.

Let $a_k$ be a known constant.  Well for every possible $b_k$ we can always have $N$ be any factor of $|b_k - a_k$ and we will have $a_k \equiv b_k \pmod N$.

And with any possible $g$ we can have $W = a + mg$ for any integer $m$ and have $a_k \equiv W \pmod g$.

So knowing that $a_k \equiv b_k \pmod g$ for *some* $g$ and for *some* $b_k$ tells us absolutely nothing.

Maybe if we knew some of the $b_k$ we could figure out the $g$ (as $g$ would have to be a factor of $|b_k -a_k|$).  But knowing none of the $b_k$ and just that $g$ we can never calculate the $b_k$ (as there are infinitely many $a_k + mg$).

[On the other hand we would also never *care* what *integer* $b_k$ is; $\mod g$ is an *equivalence* relation so if $b_k = a_k + mg$ then $b_k \equiv a_k \pmod g$ and for all intents and purposes $a_k$ and $b_k$ are completely equivalent and interchangeable and can be considered to be the exact same thing.]

But if you don't know either you know utterly nothing.

====

Howeve if the question is that the $a_k$ and $b_k$ are known, and the question is how to find $g$ the answer is:

Find the $\gcd(a_k- b_k)$.  $g$ must be a factor of $\gcd(a_k-b_k)$.

(which is probably *why* they used the letter $g$....)